# How do i differentiate between update, delete and insert event in sql after using except command in the result set?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 tables to compare. I am doing that through except command. How to i know if the output generated is an update , insert or a delete

Comment: `EXCEPT` doesn't modify the data. It just shows you rows from the first query that don't have a matching row (all columns equal) in the second query.

Comment: google  "inserted,deleted in sql server "

Comment: See the MERGE statement if you want to modify the data. Books Online > MERGE (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using FULL OUTER JOIN instead of EXCEPT to compare two tables and find records which are inserted or updated.

In below example, I assume both tables have same column structure and contain primary key.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN T1.PK IS NULL THEN 'Records only in 2nd table'
            WHEN T2.PK IS NULL THEN 'Records only in 1st table'
            WHEN T1.PK=T2.PK AND (ISNULL(T1.Column1,'')<>ISNULL(T2.Column1,'') OR ISNULL(T1.Column2,'')<>ISNULL(T2.Column2,'') OR ...) THEN 'Records updated'
            ELSE 'Records in both table are indentical'
        END,
        T1.*,
        T2.*
FROM Table1 AS T1
FULl OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON  T1.PK=T2.PK;
```